# Why a try catch when creating an audio element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just going through the Jbox plugin code, specifically the part that adds the audio and I came across the following piece of code:

```
jBox.prototype.audio = function(options) {
    options || (options = {});
    jBox._audio || (jBox._audio = {});

    // URL required, no IE8 support
    if (!options.url || this.IE8) return this;

    // Create audio if it doesn't exist
    if (!jBox._audio[options.url]) {
        var audio = jQuery('<audio/>');
        jQuery('<source/>', {src: options.url + '.mp3'}).appendTo(audio);
        jQuery('<source/>', {src: options.url + '.ogg'}).appendTo(audio);
        jBox._audio[options.url] = audio[0];
    }
    // Set volume and play audio
    jBox._audio[options.url].volume = Math.min((options.volume != undefined ? options.volume :
  (this.options.volume != undefined ? this.options.volume : 100) / 100), 1);
    jBox._audio[options.url].pause();
    try { jBox._audio[options.url].currentTime = 0; } catch (e) {}
    jBox._audio[options.url].play();

    return this;
};
```

The line of code I am having a difficulty with is the following:

```
try { jBox._audio[options.url].currentTime = 0; } catch (e) {}
```

Why is a try catch used here? I understand the usage of try catch, but in the context of this snippet of code I fail to understand the usage. Can anybody explain?

The line of code I am talking about can be found **[HERE](https://github.com/StephanWagner/jBox/blob/master/Source/jBox.js#L1587)**.

Comment: This will return the currentTime to 0, and in case that the audio didn't start yet, it might not have the _audio[option.url], and it will cause error and the script will stop. Instead, even if the script failed at that line, it will continue to .play().

Answer (score 2):

From the HTML5 spec (emphasis mine):

> On setting, **if the media element has a current media controller, then
>   the user agent must throw an InvalidStateError exception**; otherwise,
>   if the media element's readyState is HAVE_NOTHING, then it must set
>   the media element's default playback start position to the new value;
>   otherwise, it must set the official playback position to the new value
>   and then seek to the new value.

It's to handle the case where a browser doesn't know how to update the playback time yet.